# Why is the integral result of the curve of an arc negative?

Tags: integration

x=a(cos(t)^3)

y=a(sin(t)^3)

When I integrate the length of this arc, I found the result is 0：$\int_{0}^{2pi}\sqrt{(\frac{\mathrm{d} (a*(cos(t))^3)}{\mathrm{d} t})^2+(\frac{\mathrm{d} (a*(sin(t))^3)}{\mathrm{d} t})^2}dt=0$

When I integrate the 1/4 of the arc, I found the result is -1.5a: $\int_{0}^{0.5pi}\sqrt{(\frac{\mathrm{d} (a*(cos(t))^3)}{\mathrm{d} t})^2+(\frac{\mathrm{d} (a*(sin(t))^3)}{\mathrm{d} t})^2}dt=-1.5a$

Why is the integral result of the curve of an arc negative?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I have corrected it.